# What is md-item and md-item-content

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I read and html file containing the `md-item` and `md-item-content` in a [codepen](http://codepen.io/marcysutton/pen/azpmpY), where it was used within a `md-list`. I could not find any documentation for it in the angular-material's references.

what does it actually do, is it not supported any more ?

```
<md-list class="muppet-list">
        <md-item ng-repeat="it in muppets">
          <md-item-content>
            <md-button ng-click="selectMuppet(it)" ng-class="{'selected' : it === selected }">
              <img ng-src="{{it.iconurl}}" class="face" alt="">
              {{it.name}}
            </md-button>
          </md-item-content>
        </md-item>
      </md-list>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [last Angular material version](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/), i think `<md-item-content>` is deprecated.

If so, use `md-list-item`, the syntax should be:

```
<md-list>
  <md-list-item>
          Item content in list
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

See examples [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.list)

---

The `<md-item>` do nothing (suppose removed from directive list)

---

fixed <kbd>[Codepan](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJPBdN?editors=101)</kbd>

```
     <md-list class="muppet-list">
        <md-list-item ng-repeat="it in muppets">
         <md-button ng-click="selectMuppet(it)" ng-class="{'selected' : it === selected }">
              <img ng-src="{{it.iconurl}}" class="face" alt="">
              {{it.name}}
            </md-button>
        </md-list-item>
      </md-list>
```